# panic when start traefik with boltdb backend

Tags: go, traefik

I'm trying to start traefik with the boltdb backend. Sadly I always get a panic. Following my setup and the terminal output.

#### Start Command

```
./traefik_darwin-amd64 -d -c config.toml
```

#### config.toml

```
debug = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":8081"

[web]
address = ":8082"

[boltdb]
endpoint = "/Users/tochti/Tmp/traefik.db"
watch = true
prefix = "/traefik"
```

#### Terminal Output

After a long time of waiting the following panic is displayed

https://pastebin.com/1vUXbgTU

#### Output of `traefik version`: (*What version of Traefik are you using?*)

```
Version:      v1.3.1
Codename:     raclette
Go version:   go1.8.3
Built:        2017-06-16_11:00:34AM
OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
```

#### What is your environment & configuration (arguments, toml, provider, platform, ...)?

```
{
 "GraceTimeOut": 10000000000,
 "Debug": true,
 "CheckNewVersion": true,
 "AccessLogsFile": "",
 "TraefikLogsFile": "",
 "LogLevel": "ERROR",
 "EntryPoints": {
  "http": {
   "Network": "",
   "Address": ":8081",
   "TLS": null,
   "Redirect": null,
   "Auth": null,
   "Compress": false
  }
 },
 "Cluster": null,
 "Constraints": [],
 "ACME": null,
 "DefaultEntryPoints": [
  "http"
 ],
 "ProvidersThrottleDuration": 2000000000,
 "MaxIdleConnsPerHost": 200,
 "IdleTimeout": 180000000000,
 "InsecureSkipVerify": false,
 "Retry": null,
 "HealthCheck": {
  "Interval": 30000000000
 },
 "Docker": null,
 "File": null,
 "Web": {
  "Address": ":8082",
  "CertFile": "",
  "KeyFile": "",
  "ReadOnly": false,
  "Statistics": null,
  "Metrics": null,
  "Path": "",
  "Auth": null
 },
 "Marathon": null,
 "Consul": null,
 "ConsulCatalog": null,
 "Etcd": null,
 "Zookeeper": null,
 "Boltdb": {
  "Watch": true,
  "Filename": "",
  "Constraints": [],
  "Endpoint": "/Users/tochti/Tmp/traefik.db",
  "Prefix": "/traefik",
  "TLS": null,
  "Username": "",
  "Password": ""
 },
 "Kubernetes": null,
 "Mesos": null,
 "Eureka": null,
 "ECS": null,
 "Rancher": null,
 "DynamoDB": null,
 "ConfigFile": "/Users/tochti/Tmp/traefik_test/config.toml"
}
```

#### Bolt "traefik" Bucket Items

```
/traefik/backends/srv1_example_com/servers/server_1/url http://127.0.0.1:32001
/traefik/frontends/srv1_example_com/backend srv1_example_com
/traefik/frontends/srv1_example_com/routes/test_1/rule Host:srv1.example.com
```

Thanks for help!